# Getting terms and only evaluate specific parts

Tags: functions, evaluation, hold

I want to expand the expression but I do not want it to evaluate.

```
Sum[(HoldForm[1/(2 # - 1) - 1/(2 # + 1)] &)[i], {i, 1, 6}]
```

However if you evaluate this you get: `(Fraction-Fraction)+...+(Fraction-Fraction)`. What i want is to have this fraction evaluated without having to evaluate the subtraction inside the parenthesis or the addition outside the parenthesis. Could someone show me a simple way to do this?

Comment: It is a good habit to hold on with an accept a day or two, let's don't discourage others.

Comment: @Kuba Okey, ill do that next time:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
HoldForm[# - #2] & @@@ Table[{1/(2 i - 1), 1/(2 i + 1)}, {i, 1, 6}] // Total
```

> [image]

Comment: I am still (till now) don't know how to format any of my answers that way you did it here. can you tell me how? Thanks.

Comment: @Algohi The result is a picture :)

Comment: Oh, I see. I should have known this. I can't copy it:-)

Answer (score 6):

Another way of doing it (something similar to Kuba's great answer) is:

```
Sum[HoldForm[#1 - #2] &[1/(2 i - 1), 1/(2 i + 1)], {i, 1, 6}]
```

May be also something different:

```
Sum[(1/(2 i - 1) - 1/(2 i + 1) // Trace)[[-2]], {i, 1, 6}]
```

Comment: Nice! (8 to go)

Answer (score 6):

One more subtle variation:

```
Sum[Defer[# - #2] & @@ (1/(2 i + {-1, 1})), {i, 6}]
```

> ```
> (1/11 - 1/13) + (1/9 - 1/11) + (1/7 - 1/9) + (1/5 - 1/7) + (1/3 - 1/5) + (1 - 1/3)
> ```

Comment: Always new thing to the scene. When the master speech, everyone has to listen. :)