# Prevent a sum from simplifying?

Tags: output-formatting, expression-manipulation

Basically, I want to prevent a sum from cancelling or summing together the individual summands and just display them separately next to each other. Example:

```
Sum[ii,{ii,1,3}]
```

> 1+2+3

Mathematica either gives back the result `6`, or does not perform the sum at all if I use diverse `Hold` functions:

```
Sum[ii,{ii,1,3}]//Hold
```

> Hold[Sum[ii,{ii,1,3}]]

Is there any way to get the desired "halfway evaluated" output? I'd like to see every summand separately to make sure that the computation works correctly when it does a very complicated sum of variables but then reduces (mostly cancels) to a very simple answer. Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Would `HoldForm[Sum[ii, {ii,1,3}]]` suffice?

Comment: No, since it gives back the unevaluated `Sum[ii,{ii,1,3}]`, instead of the actual summands `1+2+3`.

Comment: `{a + b + c} /. {a -> "1", b -> "2", c -> "3"}`

Comment: I have marked this question as a duplicate.  Please review the link inserted at the top of your post, then tell me if anything in your question remains unanswered.

Comment: The question tagged above is very similar, but much more specialized than mine - which also becomes apparent looking at the different answers the two questions received.

Comment: Make sure to start comments with `@Mr.Wizard` if you want me to see them in a timely fashion.  You needs do seem simpler but I think that the existing answers are also applicable.  Are you unhappy with the closure?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The closure prevented a user from posting his solution as an answer, so he had to post it in the comments. I personally still received great help from the community, so that I am happy.

Comment: I am glad you received help and I am glad you are happy.  Note that the method that David proposed is exactly the same as in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71946/121).  The only difference is that the `Function` has one argument instead of two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: use `Table`

```
Sum[i^2, {i, 3}] (* 14 *)

Table[i, {i, 3}] (* {1, 4, 9} *)
```

If you want the output to be displayed like a sum, use `Row`:

```
Row[%, "+"] (* 1 + 4 + 9 *)
```

And when you want to evaluate, simply use `Total`:

```
Total[%%] (* 14 *)
```

There is another solution (see [David's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72637/prevent-a-sum-from-simplifying#comment199282_72639)):

```
Sum[(HoldForm[#] &)[i^2], {i, 3}] (* 1 + 4 + 9 *)
```

To explain how this works, let's look at it piece by piece:  First, we create a [pure function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) using `&` and `#`.  Here are a couple of (mostly) equivalent definitions to explain it:

```
f[x_] := x^2 - x + 1
f = Function[x, x^2 - x + 1];
f = Function[#^2 - # + 1];
f = (#^2 - # + 1)&;
```

You can see that in this particular case the function simply applies [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html) to the argument.  We apply this function (with the regular `[]` syntax) to each summand.  This has the effect of wrapping each summand in `HoldForm` before adding them together, preventing further evaluation of the function while displaying them normally:

```
%//InputForm (* HoldForm[1] + HoldForm[4] + HoldForm[9] *)
```

The trick is that simply using `HoldForm[i]` won't work, since `HoldForm` will prevent the summand from being evaluated, and it will remain `i^2`: you'd get `i^2 + i^2 + i^2`.  However, the argument to our anonymous function is evaluated before being passed in, so `HoldForm` is applied after the summand is evaluated.

To evaluate, simply call [`ReleaseHold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReleaseHold.html) on the expression:

```
ReleaseHold[%] (* 14 *)
```

This removes all the `HoldForm`s from the expression, allowing it to be evaluated completely.

Comment: There must be a superior way to the use of `Table`.  For instance `Sum[f[ii], {ii, 1,3}]` gives almost what the poser seeks.  Perhaps some use of an `Identity` function with `Hold` will suffice.

Comment: My logic was that if you want to "see every summand separately," then the best way was to simply generate them separately.  There might be a trick, but this solution is easy to remember and foolproof, even in weird edge cases.

Comment: Yes, this solution is great! I like how `\.List->Plus` performs the summation on it too.

Comment: One can easily imagine general cases involving `Times`, `Sum`, `Total`, etc., with non-trivial functions `f[ii]`, where the OP's desired answer would be more valuable than making a `Table` of terms.  Surely we don't want to hand code substitutions, as given by @Martin.  Moreover, if we could solve the original problem, we could more easily switch back and forth between evaluated and unevaluated outputs, especially for complex equations.

Comment: Here we go!  `Sum[(HoldForm[#] &)[ii], {ii, 1, 3}]`, and `Product[(HoldForm[#] &)[ii], {ii, 1, 3}]`, etc.  This approach permits a substitution that can "turn on" and "turn off" evaluation.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork You should post that as an answer, it's better than mine, although you should probably explain how it works.  (Note also that you can just call `ReleaseHold[%]` and the expression evaluates: that's worth a +1.)

Comment: @2012rcampion:  I would post my solution except the problem has been closed.  Oh well.  At least you know how to solve it in the future.  (You might as well +1 my comment, though!)

Comment: Could you please explain the `(HoldForm[#] &)[ii]` notation? I am most interested in knowing some details on the `#` operator in general.

Comment: @Kagaratsch please see [Pure Functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html) and [(19035)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19035/121).  Because Functions by default do not hold their arguments `HoldForm[#] &[i^2]` evaluates `i^2` and then hold the result for further evaluation, in this case later addition to other summands.