# Print integer number fraction as string of numerator and denominator

Tags: string-manipulation, style, output-formatting

I want to convert an integer number fraction as text with a certain font, size and color:

Example:

```
x = {0, 2, 3, 0, 4};
y = {4, 5, 12, 10, 1};

Style[ToString[#, TraditionalForm], FontFamily -> "Calibri", 20, 
   Red] & /@ (x/y)
```

The result is:

[image]

I would like to see the fraction values {0/4, 2/5, 3/12, 0/1, 4/1} and not the results.

Comment: One quick way is to replace `0` with `"0"`.

Comment: What is allowed to be simplified? E.g. you don't complain about 3/12.

Comment: Closely related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71938/5478

Comment: @Kuba: I would like to see the fraction values and not the results -> {0/4, 2/5, 3/12, 0/1, 4/1}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Style[ToString[#, TraditionalForm], FontFamily -> "Calibri", 20, Red] & /@ 
  (HoldForm /@ x / HoldForm /@ y)
```

[image]

Also

```
Map[Style[ToString[#, TraditionalForm], FontFamily -> "Calibri", 20, Red] &, 
  Inactivate[Divide[x, y]],  {-1}] // Activate
```

> same picture

and

```
style = Style[ToString[#, TraditionalForm], FontFamily -> "Calibri", 20, Red] &;
(style /@ x )/(style /@ y)
```

> same picture

**Update:** You can use

```
MapThread[Style[Row[{##}, "/"], FontFamily -> "Calibri", 20, Red] &, {x, y}]
```

or

```
Style[ToString[#, TraditionalForm], FontFamily -> "Calibri", 20, Red] & /@ 
  MapThread[Row[{##}, "/"] &, {x, y}]
```

to get

[image]

Comment: This is perfect. Due to space problems in my 2d plot (the fractions are used as labels for certain points and are vertically too close to each other) I would be interested to use them as a string like this: `2/5`.

Comment: @lio, please see the update.

Comment: Thank you so much ...

Comment: @lio, my pleasure.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a wrapper that formats as desired:

```
MakeBoxes[HoldRational[n_Integer, d_Integer], StandardForm] ^:= MakeBoxes[
    Style[InputForm[Divide[n, d]], FontFamily->"Calibri", FontColor->Red, 24],
    StandardForm
]
```

Then:

```
x = {0, 2, 3, 0, 4};
y = {4, 5, 12, 10, 1};

MapThread[HoldRational, {x, y}]
```

[image]